# (Odoo) Store field names into a selection field of a separate model

Tags: odoo, backend

How should I get all of the field names from the product.template model and store them in a selection field in a separate model?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqsTX.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue with the code below, I tried using self in the method get_fields but the following `KeyError: product.template` occurred so too bypass that I used request instead of self.

The selection field consists of [(product_template_field_name_1, product_template_field_name_string_1),..,(product_template_field_name_n, product_template_field_name_string_n)], n being the number of fields in the product.template model.

```
from odoo.http import request

def get_fields(self):
    fields = [(field, request.env['product.template']._fields[field].string) for field in
              request.env["product.template"]._fields]

    return fields

field_name = fields.Selection(
    selection=lambda self: self.get_fields(),
    required=True)
```